# Using UIButtons to move left, right, up and down in a zoomed in UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, core-graphics

I searched many resources with no result so far.

I'm able to successfully zoom in/out and move left, right, up and down by swiping in a UIImageView under it a ScrollView.

How to achieve the same by using buttons? I could do the zoom in and zoom out using this code:

```
@IBAction func zoomIn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    if imageScrollView.zoomScale < imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale {
        imageScrollView.zoomScale = imageScrollView.zoomScale + 0.1
    }
}

@IBAction func zoomOut(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
    if imageScrollView.zoomScale > imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale {
        imageScrollView.zoomScale = imageScrollView.zoomScale - 0.1
    }
}
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageScrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size
    imageScrollView.delegate = self
  }


override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
}

// MARK: - Calculation of zoom scale for imageScrollView
fileprivate func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
    let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
    let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
    let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

    imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    imageScrollView.zoomScale = minScale
}
```

I need to add 4 more buttons in a shape of arrows to move left, right, up and down. The purpose of doing all this is because I want to draw and zoom in a UIImageView at the same time and that's causing conflicts.

Comment: Whats the conflict are you getting? If you are able to scroll or zoom in/out, what the issue are you facing in putting that logic in button action? Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Add the four buttons and map each one to the following actions. If you're not using `autolayout` then this would work:

```
@IBAction func moveLeft(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  imageScrollView.frame.origin.x -= 10.0
}

@IBAction func moveRight(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  imageScrollView.frame.origin.x += 10.0
}

@IBAction func moveUp(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  imageScrollView.frame.origin.y += 10.0
}

@IBAction func moveDown(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  imageScrollView.frame.origin.y -= 10.0
}
```